# How can I pass the request variable with Python?

Tags: python, authentication, request

I would like to automate a site login with Python.
When I investigate the query in Firefox I see the followings:

```
POST http://IP:PORT/?%7B%22request%22%3A%22postRequest%22%7D=

URL Parameters
{"request":"postRequest"}

Body
{"request":"login","data":{"login":"asd","password":"asdasd"}}

Headers
{"Content-Type"}:{"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
```

I tried the following code but I got "NO_REQUEST_VARIABLE" error message from the server.

```
url = "http://IP:PORT"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url,
           params={"request":"postRequest"},
           data={"request":"login","data":{"login":"asd","password":"asdasd"}},
           headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})
print(r.text)
```

Then, tried to achieve this in Firefox and it happens when I delete *"request"* from the body part.

What's wrong with my Python query?

Comment: Something isn't right. The body in Firefox is JSON, not URL-encoded.

Comment: try changing `data=` to `json=`.

Comment: What is the HTTP response code? For some unknown reason you don't seem to be checking that

Comment: Response code is 200 (OK)

Comment: If you're getting HTTP 200 then that suggests that your payload (JSON) is malformed - i.e., may be valid JSON but not in the format the server was expecting. Is the host:port publicly available?

Comment: Sorry it's not available because it is behind vpn and I'm not the person who can control this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a pattern that you could employ to POST a JSON payload.

This uses the publicly available https://httpbin.org website.

Some of the data are based on OP's question.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
PARAMS = {
    "request": "postRequest"
}
PAYLOAD = {
    "request": "login",
    "data": {
        "login": "asd",
        "password": "asdasd"
    }
}
HEADERS = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post(URL, json=PAYLOAD, params=PARAMS, headers=HEADERS)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())
```

This shows a normal/expected response

Answer (score 0):

Well, there must have something to do with this.

```
headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
```

You see `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but it must be `application/JSON`, it's the standard in most browsers.

---

If it doesn't work too, try changing also this...

```
data={"request":"login","data":{"login":"asd","password":"asdasd"}}
```

...to this...

```
json={"request":"login","data":{"login":"asd","password":"asdasd"}},
```

Comment: Tried both but problem is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have your same "request-receiver" to test the Python code on, if the answer won't have been of any help when you solve the problem, please send me a comment and I'll delete the answer :) I don't have a bare idea of what else could be wrong.

Comment: Useful, I just said I tried.